# Why my loadUrl can't work on

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm beginner in adroid
i want ask why if i used loadUrl and i execute the program always page can't found

this my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        String url = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41HGB-W2Z8L._SL500_AA300_.jpg";
        wv.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

thx before..

Comment: Is there any error in log?? if it so please post it.

Comment: Have you enabled javascript in the code? I think that's the issue @Rio

Answer (score 1):

you need to add internet permission in manifest file..

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my application. 99% sure you forgot to include the INTERNET permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```